# Remove Eclipse plugin from outside of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

After I install the Enhanced Class Decompiler plugin, my customized Eclipse can't start. I copied and pasted the URL onto the add software panel as I did for other plugins. It says

```
An error has occurred.
See the log file /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configure/1623...log
```

I, however, don't see the log file in the directory.

The only log file in the directory has only one line with one word.

```
!SESSION
```

I have to remove the plugin for now.

How to do so from outside of Eclipse?

Comment: How did you install it? Please share the link from where you install it.

Comment: I copied and pasted the URL onto the add software panel as I did for other plugins

Comment: Which URL and what did you select to install? Does the following work? https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Revert_an_Update_or_Installation_with_p2

Comment: Thanks for the info. It doesn't work for me. I use the gz entry with the latest timestamp. I reinstall the Eclipse to overcome the problem.